# Is Redux a single point of failure for whole application?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've encountered [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) recently which manages application state centrally.

If it manages state *centrally* then it must be a single point of failure for whole application if yes then how can we eliminate this risk? Please elaborate the reason otherwise.

Thanks

Comment: By following this logic React (or whatever framework you're using) is a single point of failure too.

Comment: @gronostaj I think if we are using just React, it's components manage their state locally on their own which makes it non single point failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always have fallback methods for failure. every language and technology will fail if you don't have fallback precautions.

Like for example in case of redux, if redux's not working. Code something to handle it, don't leave the user confused.

Read this, [Deal with Failure in Redux](https://medium.com/iadvize-engineering/how-to-deal-with-failure-in-redux-connect-ec17eec6b6e2)